# How to write a custom Control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio

i try to write a custom user control to filter data to reflect to GridView.if you look USAGE i try to write:

[image]

important: i am using DynamicLinq!!!!!

But Error return me when Clicking Search Button:

#### Error:

No property or field 'Chai' exists in type 'Product'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts; // Ekle
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; // Ekle
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Reflection;// Ekle

namespace MyControl2
{
    public class TestControl : WebPart
    {
        internal List<Content> list { get; set; }
        public Button BtnSearch { get; set; }
        public event EventHandler Click;
        public TestControl()
        {
            list = new List<Content>();
            BtnSearch = new Button();
            BtnSearch.ID = "btnSearch";
            BtnSearch.Text = "Search";
            this.Controls.Add(BtnSearch);
            BtnSearch.Click += new EventHandler(BtnSearch_Click);

        }

        void BtnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</tr><table>"));

            foreach (var item in this.Controls)
            {
                if (item is MyTextBoxControl)
                {
                    MyTextBoxControl t1 = (MyTextBoxControl)item;
                    if (t1.Text != "")
                    {
                        Add(new Content() { FieldName = t1.ID, Data = t1.Text, ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), DataType=t1.DataType  });
                    }
                }
            }
            Click(this, e);

        }

        public string QueryParameters()
        {
            string Qry=String.Empty;
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Qry += item.FieldName + "=" + item.Data + " and ";
                i++;
            }
            Qry = Qry.TrimEnd('A', 'n', 'd',' ');
            return Qry;
        }
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
                base.CreateChildControls();
                this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr>"));
        }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public void AddItem(ContentItem content )
        {
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new Label() { ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = content.LabelName });
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(":</td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<td>"));
            this.Controls.Add(new MyTextBoxControl() { ID = content.FieldName, DataType= content.DataType });
            this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td>"));
       }
        private void Add(Content content)
        {
            list.Add(new Content() { ID = content.ID, Data = content.Data, FieldName = content.FieldName });
        }
    }

    internal class Content
    {
        internal string ID { get; set; }
        public string Data { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContentItem
    {
        private string ID { get; set; }
        public string LabelName { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string DataType { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyTextBoxControl : TextBox
    {
        public string DataType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### USAGE

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
                base.OnInit(e);
                FilterControl1.AddItem(new FlyAntFilterControl.ContentItem() { LabelName = "Product", FieldName = "ProductName" });
                FilterControl1.Click += new EventHandler(FilterControl1_Click);

        }

        void FilterControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DataClasses1DataContext DataCtx = new DataClasses1DataContext())
            {
                var qry = DataCtx.Products.Where(FilterControl1.QueryParameters());
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

#### ScreenShoots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chai is not a PropertyName, Chai is a Variable of the Property "ProductName", What is 'member'?

Comment: Sorry; Robbie i don't understand your question.

Comment: the Error your getting is that There is No Property on the object that has a name called "Chai", the Property is called "ProductName", is the Code that it is failing on Pre Generated code from Visual Studio? If not Post the Function or routine where the Error is occuring, so we can see it in full. It looks to me Like it is trying to work out what the Unknown Type is and its then trying to find "Chai" as a property for some reason. What are you pressing for the Error to be Caught?

Comment: In your screen shot showing the exception, the code is trying to find a Property called "Chai". However, the actual Property name is going to be "ProductName" - "Chai" is the *value* of this property (for ProductID 2). It might be useful if you could post the text of the code in the screenshot, then we can see what this variable called "member" is.

Answer (score 2):

@Penguen -

You have a Product *class* with *properties* or *attributes* called:

- ProductID
- ProductName
- CategoryID

And actual *Products* with **VALUES** e.g.:

ProductId: 1
ProductName: Boston Crabmeat
CategoryID: 1

ProductId: 2
ProductName: Chai
CategoryID: 2

ProductId: 3
ProductName: Chocolate Biscuits
CategoryID: 3

This isn't exactly what your code is trying to do, but should help you see what's wrong. Let's create an *instance* of a Product:

```
myProduct = new Product(2,"Chai", 2);
```

To access that product's *values*, you should do something like this:

```
myProduct.ProductName;  //Correct :-)
```

But your code is doing something like this:

```
myProduct.Chai;         //Wrong :-(
```

"Chai" is not a *property* - ProductName is the property. One of your Product *instances* has a *value* of "Chai".

In your GridView you *might* be doing something like:

```
<%# Eval("Chai") %>
```

when it should be:

```
<%# Eval("ProductName") %>
```

Hard to tell for sure until you post a fuller code example ;-)

Hope this helps.